# How can I put an array of objects into another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array, `copyCommands`, that I want to push some items into. However, I can't seem to correctly add another array of items into the parent object `autoGenData`.

```
//autoGenData is the object, copyCommands is an array

        autoGenData.copyCommands.push({
            CopyFrom: UnitFrom,
            //CopyTo: //array that needs to hold CopyOptions and Unit
        });

            //Need to add these into CopyTo 
            //CopyOptions: checkedItems,
            //Unit: localUnitTo
```

What's the proper syntax for adding `CopyOptions` and `unit` to the `CopyTo` portion of the `push` command?

Comment: Are CopyOptions and Unit also arrays?

Comment: They are elements of an array that I want to create -- `copyTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
autoGenData.copyCommands.push({
  CopyFrom: UnitFrom,
  CopyTo: {
    CopyOptions: checkedItems,
    Unit: localUnitTo
  }
});
```

Comment: This is it! Didn't realize you could write a nested command like that.

Comment: Isn't CopyTo an array of CopyOptions and Unit?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var y = [5, 6, 7];
x.push(...y);
```